# Not getting the updated value of ngModel at custom validator in primeng p-calendar

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am trying to use an `p-calendar` with icon like this

```
                 <p-calendar 
                        [showOnFocus]="false"
                        [locale]="sw"
                        dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
                        [style]="{'width': '120px'}"
                        [showIcon]="true"
                        [(ngModel)]="abc.efg.fromDate"
                        [check]="checkDate()"

                        [keepMessage]="true"
                        [keepInvalid]="true"
                        (onSelect)="dateOnSelect(abc.efg, $event)"
                        alwaysShow></p-calendar>
```

and the implementation of checkDate() in the app component looks like this

```
checkDate(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
      console.log('date from : ', this.abc.efg.fromDate);
      // other implementation
              }
      }
```

The issue I am facing is that, whenever I pick a date (by clicking the icon), I get call in the checkDate() and the value of `this.abc.efg.fromDate` is always `null`, but I am getting the value of `this.abc.efg.fromDate` in the function `dateOnSelect($event)`

```
 setDateOnSelect(Type t, event): void {
    t.fromDate = event;
    console.log('new date from: ', this.abc.efg.fromDate);
  }
```

How can I solve this ?

EDIT: Is there anything that I can do at the validator other than directly passing the value to the function. ?

My guess : Angular's two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]` is asynchronous, and changes might not be reflected immediately in the validation function. Any idea to overcome this ?

PS: `this.abc.efg.fromDate` is a date field.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue, you can use **"ngModelChange"**. This directly captures the change and return the value.

```
<p-calendar 
  [showOnFocus]="false"
  [locale]="sw"
  dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
  [style]="{'width': '120px'}"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="abc.efg.fromDate"
  [keepMessage]="true"
  [keepInvalid]="true"
  (onSelect)="dateOnSelect($event)"
  (ngModelChange)="checkDate($event)"
  alwaysShow>
</p-calendar>
```

Create a function in your ts file.

```
checkDate(newDate: any){
  console.log(newDate);
}
```

Hope this works and fix your issue.

Comment: Okay, add   [check]="checkDate" this. Dont use brackets to call function. Just the name.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: <p-calendar 
  [showOnFocus]="false"
  [locale]="sw"
  dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
  [style]="{'width': '120px'}"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="abc.efg.fromDate"
  [keepMessage]="true"
  [keepInvalid]="true"
  (onSelect)="dateOnSelect($event)"
  (ngModelChange)="checkDate($event)"
  [check]="checkDate"
  alwaysShow>
</p-calendar>

Comment: Actually when I do the validation on ngModelChange, the validator function checkDate() is not even called.

Comment: it might be due to the fact that the [check] property is expecting a validator function, and it might not be aware of the (ngModelChange) event binding.

Comment: Change your code like this : <p-calendar 
  [showOnFocus]="false"
  [locale]="sw"
  dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
  [style]="{'width': '120px'}"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="abc.efg.fromDate"
  [keepMessage]="true"
  [keepInvalid]="true"
  (onSelect)="dateOnSelect($event)"
  (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)"
  [check]="checkDate"
  alwaysShow>
</p-calendar>

Comment: and for ts file:
onDateChange(newDate: any): void {
  this.abc.efg.fromDate = newDate;
  this.checkDate();
}

checkDate(): void {
  console.log('Validating date:', this.abc.efg.fromDate);
  // Your validation logic here
}

Comment: yes, that's exactly what's happening. Any idea how I could resolve this ?

Comment: Please check the above answer

Comment: If issue still arises, can you create a stackblitz for this and share

Answer (score 0):

The data was binding perfectly with

```
[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
```

For some reason `ngModelChange` was not working for me.